# Powershell - filtering WMIObject processes by more than one name

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to get a list of running processes and filter by two process names - can any one tell me how to get this working?

I've so far got it working and filtering out one process name:

```
$rn = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -computer servername `
  -credential mydomain\administrator -filter "Name='program1.exe'" |
  select -expand path
$lst = Get-Content “C:\path\path2\List.txt”
Compare-Object $lst $rn
```

What I want it to do is filter two process names but nothing I've tried works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of the processes you're after:

```
$processes = @('winword.exe', 'notepad.exe', 'excel.exe') | `
    % {
       $rn = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -computer servername -credential mydomain\admin -filter "Name='$_'" | select -expand path 
       #$lst = Get-Content “C:\path\path2\List.txt” 
       #Compare-Object $lst $rn
       write-host $rn
    }
```

I've commented out your compare so you can see how we are looping through the array clearly.

Answer (score 6):

Use WQL operators like OR, AND, LIKE etc:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -computer servername -credential mydomain\administrator -filter "Name='program1.exe' OR Name='program2.exe'"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to get a complete set of Process objects which match a list of process names you're interested in.

```
$ProcessNames = @( 'explorer.exe', 'notepad.exe' )

Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer 'localhost' |
  Where-Object { $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name } | 
  Select-Object ProcessID, Name, Path |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This example finds all processes, then filters that list by sending them to a pipeline filter that checks to see if the process name is contained in the list of interesting process names. The main benefit of using the pipeline this way is that you can easily access other attributes (such as ProcessID) of the returned processes.

```
ProcessID Name         Path
--------- ----         ----
     5832 explorer.exe C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
     4332 notepad.exe  C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE
     2732 notepad.exe  C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well try this:

```
$rn = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -computer servername -credential mydomain\administrator -filter "Name='program1.exe OR Name='program2.exe'"
Compare-Object $rn[0].path $rn[1].path # if there are only one instance for process with name program1.exe and program2.exe
```